# Install .NET Framework 4.6 on ubuntu

Tags: .net, ubuntu

I need to install an `.exe` application on Ubuntu with Wine. When I try to install it, the installer launches a pop-up that says:

> .NET Framework needs to be installed for this version of the software.

Can I do something about this?